# how can i get data from Principal in controller?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using Spring Boot and Spring Security.

I would like to get current authenticated user data inside my userController (not only the name, username, password and authorities)

I found on differents links I can use Principal in my requestMapping method.
But how can I data on this principal please ?

If I run in debug mode I can see all data I need inside the Principal variable.

```
@GetMapping("/users")
public ResponseEntity<?> getAllUsers(Principal principal) {
    
    return this.userService.getAllUsers();
}
```

[image]

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security

Comment: i saw this post, but I expect it is possible to get data from Principale since i can see data in variable debug mode, no ?

Comment: you need to cast it to a userdetails object so that the compiler knows what object it is and what methods exist on the object.

Comment: It does not work with Principale. But it works with Authentication but it does not give me more details than username, email and authorities. I need the others variables

Comment: I solved my problem and edited my post. Thanks

Comment: Please don't edit the question to include a solution. Instead, post an answer in the answer box.

Answer (score 0):

you hard cast it to a user details object:

```
final UserDetails currentUser = (UserDetails) ((Authentication) principal).getPrincipal();
```